# How to animate second Activity from bottom to top?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have a click button on first activity and when we click on that button then I want to animate second activity but in my case my first activity also animated with second 
here is code

```
 Intent createCompaignActivityIntent = new Intent(mActivity, CreateCompaignActivity.class);
 mActivity.startActivity(createCompaignActivityIntent);
 mActivity.overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

slide_out_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to animate your first Activity, then change `android:toYDelta="-100%p"` to `android:toYDelta="0%p"` in your slide_out_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

**Edit:**

To achieve slide down on exit of second activity, create a animation file and copy below code

slide_out_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and in your second activity's `onBackPressed()` add the below code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_up, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I want to implement on second activity from top to bottom animation and finish second activity when animation end